# How to enable lightdm as lock-screen in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: lock-screen

How to set lock-screen to lightdm logon? Now the lock screen is ugly. I googled and said it was carried into ubuntu 12.04 already. But I can't found this feature even in 12.10 now. Anyone can help or explain?

Comment: Yeah, the Unity Greeter is supposed to manage the lock screen.  I have no idea how to enable this.  See here for an example: http://cloudfront.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/new-lightdm-lockscreen.jpg

Comment: @kedmond: your URL 404 error.

Comment: Thanks.  Here's an alternative link: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/a-handful-of-minor-ubuntu-12-04-updates

I think the feature was removed at the last minute due to complications with Nvidia drivers...bummer.